# How to transpose and insert a Pandas column slice into a row slice?

Tags: python, pandas, insert, slice, transpose

Trying to take a slice of a column from one Pandas dataframe, transpose the slice, and insert it into a similarly sized row slice, in a different dataframe. Labels and indexes in both dataframes are different. With large dataframes, am currently running a for loop to copy each individual value, cell-by-cell as it were, but incredibly inefficient.

Other than for-loop, have tried .loc, .iloc, with transpose, but no success. pivot, pivot_table, melt dont seem to be applicable here, or I cannot get my head around how to apply them to this seemingly simple problem.

```
# Two dataframes here
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
numRng = np.arange(20).reshape((5, 4))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(numRng)
newCols = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
for newCol in newCols:
    df1[newCol] = np.nan 
numRng2 = np.arange(1000,976,-1).reshape((6, 4))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(numRng2)
df2.columns = ['M', 'N', 'O', 'P']
```

df1
[image: target dataframe]

df2
[image: source dataframe]

```
# From df1, trying to copy a column-slice, transpose it, and insert it 
# into df2 row-slice, has no effect
df1.loc[1, 'B':'E'] = df2.loc[1:4, 'M'].transpose()
df1

# 'Manual' implementation to produce desired df1 geometry
df1.loc[1, 'B'] = 996
df1.loc[1, 'C'] = 992
df1.loc[1, 'D'] = 988
df1.loc[1, 'E'] = 984
df1
```

In example df's above, in df1 row1 columns B, C, D, E show numbers 996, 992, 988 and 984 in the row slice.

[image: Desired df1 output geometry]

How to extract slice, transpose and insert without for-looping over every value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to numpy array for avoid data alignment - pandas try match index and columns each other and if failed, create missing values or not assign values:

```
#pandas 0.22+
df1.loc[1, 'B':'E'] = df2.loc[1:4, 'M'].transpose().to_numpy()
#pandas below
#df1.loc[1, 'B':'E'] = df2.loc[1:4, 'M'].transpose().values

print (df1)
    0   1   2   3   A      B      C      D      E   F
0   0   1   2   3 NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
1   4   5   6   7 NaN  996.0  992.0  988.0  984.0 NaN
2   8   9  10  11 NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
3  12  13  14  15 NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
4  16  17  18  19 NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
```

Comment: Thx jezrael. I did try some variant of to_numpy previously, unsuccessfully.Your simple version worked perfectly.